# Unable to build Jenkins script

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins, seleniumbase

I have selenium/python frame that I would like to push and use with jenkins.

However, while trying to build the script I get following error:

```
Started by user Dusan Kovacevic
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /Users/dusandev/.jenkins/workspace/SeleniumBase
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential somecredentials
> git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir 
/Users/dusandev/.jenkins/workspace/SeleniumBase/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/StreamFlow-Finance/automated-web- 
tests.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/StreamFlow-Finance/automated-web- 
tests.git
> git --version # timeout=10
> git --version # 'git version 2.34.1'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
> git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/StreamFlow- 
Finance/automated-web-tests.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
> git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/main^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 82fe529ff81267aebb97098fb92e4401abfe0462 
(refs/remotes/origin/main)
> git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> git checkout -f 82fe529ff81267aebb97098fb92e4401abfe0462 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Add files via upload"
> git rev-list --no-walk 82fe529ff81267aebb97098fb92e4401abfe0462 # timeout=10
[SeleniumBase] $ /bin/sh -xe 
/var/folders/nb/qbb9ctrn3rb68w54m_yyyqhh0000gn/T/shiningpanda17442261483823605080.sh
+ python -m venv env
+ call ./env/Scripts/activate.bat
/var/folders/nb/qbb9ctrn3rb68w54m_yyyqhh0000gn/T/shiningpanda17442261483823605080.sh: 
line 3: call: command not found
Build step 'Custom Python Builder' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Here is what I have under build command in Jenkins:

```
python -m venv env
call ./env/Scripts/activate.bat
pip install -r requirements.txt
sbase install chromedriver latest
pytest --headless
```

What I'm trying to do is set up remote testing capabilities. Other teammates being able to run tests whenever they want.

Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: You are running the virtualenv command on a linux machine and therefore to activate the virtual environment you should use the following command: `source 'env/bin/activate'`. See the [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) for more info.

Comment: thanks @NoamHelmer that was the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps in order to call a .bat file from a Jenkins script, you need to write it like below.

```
start cmd.exe /c ./env/Scripts/activate.bat
```